# Instagram api users

Tags: instagram-api

I have already taken the permission of public_content scope.

Following php code, I created.

There is not data return, in case of user($id5) is not the owner of the access_token.

Appreciate any help.

-user is exist.

-If user is the owner, there is return data.

php code:
$json5 = @file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$id5}/?access_token=[MY-ACCESS-TOKEN]");

$json_deco5 = json_decode($json5, true);

print_r($json_deco5);

This code is created by following page:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason of not data return.
[MY-ACCESS-TOKEN] was wrong.

**Poceedure must be:**
The User(not the owner of the access_token) have to login into instagram and agree to profile data.
Then code will be return.
By this code, you access again into API.
Then ACCESS-TOKEN will be return.

http://www.ijtc.co.jp/instagram_api